# Charge-Dipole Derivation - How To Know When To Use The Taylor Expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion

First, a side question. I was going through the derivation found at:

https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~mevans/em/lec5.pdf

My first question: Where does the cos(theta) come from in the equation just below (1)? $$\frac{a}{r}{cos\theta}$$

Main question. In this derivation of the charge-dipole interaction, starting on page 6:

https://cpb-us-e1.wpmucdn.com/sites.northwestern.edu/dist/8/1599/files/2017/06/taylor_series-14rhgdo.pdf

A Taylor Expansion is used to determine how the electric field behaves at x >> a. My question is about Taylor Expansions in general.  Looking at the three equations (8) on page 6, I would never have guessed or thought to use a Taylor Expansion.  I know how to use the Taylor Expansion for the typical equations (i.e. $e^x$, $sin(x)$, etc...), but I really struggle with recognizing when to use it.  This derivation is a perfect example.  What in this equation would give me a clue to use the Taylor Expansion? Why does an expansion need to be used here?

Comment: Hi, welcome to math.SE! You can get the proper font for functions like $\cos$ by using `\cos`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}` for the same effect. The command for $\gg$ is `\gg`. Please see [this tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) on how to typeset math on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$cos(\theta)$ is the angle that comes from the product $a\cdot r$.

About Taylor expansions, it's more a matter of practice. In general, when you have an expression in the form $(X)^-k$, and $X$ is your variable, you want to do a low-order approximation if possible. And sometimes, Taylor expansion can help to solve integral.

Here, you have $(1-a/x)^-2$ which is kind of hard to get a behaviour, so you have to do an expansion.

Once again, it's more a matter of practice and experience, it's part of the things that come with time.

Comment: Ok, that definitely helps my understanding.  Could you expound a bit on the "hard to get a behaviour" part?  I am quite the novice when it comes to recognizing how equations like this behave or rather don't behave.

Comment: @kmcguir Well the Taylor expansion predicts the behaviour near a certain point. Here, it is the behaviour when a/x is near zero. When you have a complicated expression, you want to know its "hehaviour", the values it will take, near a point, on a interval that you WILL use physically. Here, as $a/x$ is always near 0, then the taylor expansion of order 1 is a good approximation for the model used here. However, it will be a BAD approximation when $a/x$ is big.

Comment: Ok, I see that makes sense.  One last question, and I think I've got it. I might it missed it in the derivation or the reading, but why is a/x always near zero here? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @kmcguir You wrote $x >> a$  then $1 >> a/x$

Comment: Got it! Thanks! I never got to ask questions like these during class because I didn't want to look stupid to the other students and waste the professor's time. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @kmcguir If you are new to the site, you are supposed to award the best answer to the multiple answers you got on a question.